Has the Watchtower addressed why they haven't released their own Hebrew Interlinear of the Old Testament?
Follow up question to Where can I find a Jehovah's Witnesses version of a Hebrew Interlinear Old Testament?

FWIW, like other churches, Watchtower Society have used the existing interlinears and manuscripts that have been already available. The Greek Interlinear they published was originally made by Westcott and Hort; the Watchtower Society obtained the rights to it and continued its publication. So they have produced neither a Hebrew or a Greek interlinear themselves.

This article
provides information from their publication "Reasoning From the Scriptures" about the sources used in the New World Translation of the Hebrew Scriptures:

As a basis for translating the Hebrew Scriptures, the text of Rudolf Kittel's 'Biblia Hebraica' editions of 1951-1955, was used. The 1984 revision of the New World Translation benefited from updating in harmony with the 'Biblia Stuttgartensia' of 1977. Additionally, the Dead Sea Scrolls and numerous early translations into other languages were consulted. For the Christian Greek Scriptures, the master Greek text of 1881 as prepared by Westcott and Hort was used primarily, but several other master texts were consulted as well as numerous early versions in other languages.

You ask why they have not released their own Kingdom Interlinear Translation of the Hebrew Scriptures.
To do that, they would need accredited Hebrew scholars.  Perhaps they don't have any.  Even if they did, they would never be identified so it would be impossible to check on their scholastic credentials:

Since the translators have chosen to remain anonymous, the question cannot here be answered in terms of their educational background. The translation must be appraised on its own merits.


No.  They have not commented on a Hebrew interlinear.
Here is the website
Where they make no mention of ever having contemplated producing a Hebrew interlinear.

Kris, we know there has never been a Kingdom Interlinear Translation of the Hebrew Scriptures.  The OP wants to know why.

@Lesley  op wants to know if the subject has been addressed. The answer is no

@Kris  The OP would like to know why the Watchtower Society has never produced their own Hebrew Interlinear, hence asking if they have "addressed" that fact. If they have addressed that fact, then there might be something written about it. If there is nothing written about it (as seems to be the case, certainly not on their web-site) then the reason will remain secret to those few in leadership who decide what is to be published, and what is not - and why. So, the OPs question cannot be answered, except by someone high up in their leadership, which I don't suppose you are.

@anne the op can edit the question to make it  unanswerable.    As it is currently written the answer is “No the watchtower has not addressed why they have not released a Hebrew interlinear.   If Op had asked why hasn’t watchtower released a Hebrew interlinear, I would not have answered.
